Нужна ли запятая перед И? Слово ПРОСТО является общим?
Просто эти ребята с твёрдым характером и у нее никак не получается их смягчить.
Нужна ли запятая перед И? Слово "просто" является здесь общим?
По смыслу слово "просто" относится и ко второй части: Просто у нее никак не получается их смягчить, ведь эти ребята с твердым характером.

Но предложение такое длинное, что просится пауза, чтобы 
перевести дух.

Я выбираю вариант с запятой:
Просто эти ребята с твёрдым харАктером, // и у нее никак не получается их смягчить.
Пояснение
Решаем задачу с учетом семантики, грамматики и интонации.

По грамматике простые предложения в составе ССП  можно связать союзом И, если они семантически однородны, то есть независимы и не связаны причинно-следственными отношениями.

Но такие отношения здесь явно присутствуют, иначе говоря, это логическое рассуждение: Так как ребята с твёрдым характером, то  у нее никак не получается их смягчить. Тогда запятую нужно поставить, отношения неоднородные.

В другой стороны, такая взаимообусловленность учитывается не всегда, и условно их можно считать независимыми, если этот вопрос (с точки зрения семантики) не является принципиальным. В этом случае это авторская (эмоциональная) оценка ситуации, и тогда частица просто может считаться общей.

Но надо сделать выбор. Тогда учитывается  грамматическая структура ССП. Оно распространенное (длинное), у второго простого предложения есть собственный распространитель (у нее), так что прочитать предложение в одну фонетическую фразу (без паузы) сложно. И мы ставим запятую, обозначая грамматическую паузу.

Попробуем упростить предложение: Просто (= иначе говоря, другими словам) ребята с твёрдым характером и смягчить их трудно.  Здесь это вывод, указание общей причины. Запятая не ставится.



"Иначе говоря" обособляется.

Да, обособляется в качестве вводного слова, которое тоже может быть общим элементом, как и частица.

Может, я просто НРКЯ полистал, там куча примеров, и везде обособляется.

Вводное слово обособляется? Да, обязательно, но на наше предложение это не повлияет.  (1) Иначе говоря, ребята с твёрдым характером и смягчить их трудно.  (2) Иначе говоря, эти ребята с твёрдым харАктером,  и у нее никак не получается их смягчить.

Тогда я равенства не понимаю в части "5" - "Просто (= иначе говоря, другими словам)."

В п.5  слова просто, иначе говоря, другими словами я считаю синонимами со значением вывода их предыдущего контекста.  ССП воспринимается как единое суждение. // Если поставить запятую, то "просто" будет относиться к первому предложению, а во втором предложении будет обозначено следствие из первого  Здесь два отдельных суждения.

В моём понимании "синоним", он синоним, если не меняет синтаксиса и грамматики, ну и значение сохраняет примерное. А тут синтаксис меняется, значит равенства не верно. То есть если например, слово прилагательное, а синоним не прилагательное - то это не синоним)) Вот и тут получается "просто" - это вводное. А до этого было вроде не вводное, или я невнимательно прочитал.

Какая вам разница, частица или вводное слово? У обоих оценочное значение, оба отнесены ко всему составу предложения. Синтаксическая синонимия.  А если "проще говоря"?  Это уже вводное слово.

Если вводное, как "иначе говоря", - то нужно обособлять, а если нет, то не нужно. В итоге там есть запятая после "просто"?

Зачем запятая,  не нужна запятая)

Ох, если "просто"="иначе говоря", а "иначе говоря" обособляется обычно, так как вводное, то и тут запятая нужна, или нет?

Нет.  Синтаксическая синонимия. Необособленная частица или обособленное вводное слово – все одно. Оба варианта могут быть общим элементом  в ССП.

Вот статейка есть на эту тему с хорошим названием  https://proza.ru/2022/10/05/622

И так и так можно. Можно "просто" выделить запятой, тогда получится вводное или модальное - "по-простому", условие ~ если просто, очень просто, а сказать просто, проще говоря и тп.  И тогда нужна запятая между сложносочинёнными частями.
"(Очень)Просто, эти ребята с твёрдым характером, и у нее никак не получается их смягчить," - логическое рассуждение.

— Я забыл спросить, как ты добралась? Вернее, не успел.
— Очень просто, ночным автобусом.
Сергей Довлатов. Заповедник (1983)
Зашел разговор о лошадях, и Печорин начал расхваливать лошадь Казбича:
уж такая-то она резвая, красивая, словно серна, — ну, просто, по
его словам, этакой и в целом мире нет. Лермонтов.

А если запятой не обособляется, тогда "просто" = "это просто" - просто+местоимение(местоимение+просто) - говорящий воспринимает это как что-то простое не требующее сложных размышлений. То есть если условие - тогда нужна запятая, а если это эмоциональная окраска - то не нужна. Тогда запятые не нужны.
"Просто эти ребята с твёрдым характером и у нее никак не получается их смягчить," - эмоциональное - "я догадался! Это просто!", "это очень просто, пойми", тогда можно без запятых. Но зависит от того, что просто - просто всё вместе(посылка и вывод) или проста только первая часть(тогда запятая перед И нужна).
Можно сравнить с запятой и без:

Просто нам плохо будет, а не туркам. Гоголь.
— Как же, братец, не смутиться, — отвечал Фирс Игнатьич, — что ж она говорила? скажи, пожалуйста. — Просто, она влюблена в вас. — Полно, братец, этого быть не может! А. Ф. Вельтман. Приключения, почерпнутые из моря житейского. Саломея (1848)
...просто, я не храбр... Толстой.

Однако, вторая форма - это скорее разговорное или диалоговое. Наверное так)

Классно рассуждаете!  Интересный и оригинальный взгляд, но в принципе верный. В подобных сообщениях возможны оба решения. Надо только грамматики добавить для солидности))  Лицеприятный отзыв?)

Грамматику не разумею) Лестный)(кстати, антоним и оба слова можно воспринять в негативном ключе, а можно и в позитивном)

Я без лести, вы мне верите?)

Да я шучу. Вы очень тепло поддерживаете то, что считаете верным, верю конечно, хотя мне это лестно, в том числе.

просто, нареч. и частица
Выдержка из словаря

@IrinaWulf Если можно вставить слово "очень/если" - "очень просто/если просто", - тогда обособляется, если нельзя, тогда не обособляется. Тут можно и так и так.

@IrinaWulf но семантика фраз будет различна.

Это сложносочинённое предложение, здесь две грамматические основы: ...ребята с твердым характером и у нее никак не получается...
В таких предложениях перед союзом и ставится запятая.

Серж, здесь речь идет об общем элементе в ССП. Частица просто может быть здесь общим элементом?  Розенталь:  5) В некоторых случаях общим элементом может быть частица (ограничительная, усилительная, выделительная): В воздухе тишина; только поскрипывает на берегу кузнечик да где-то робко мурлыкает орличка (Ч.). http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133

В данном случае частица "просто" относится к первой части, поэтому запятая ставится. Нельзя сказать: просто эти ребята с твердым характером и просто у нее никак не получается их смягчить.

Возможно, что и так, но желательно записать это в ответе. Здесь два решения, а вот обоснования могут быть разные.  С этими общими элементами много проблем.  В частности решение зависит от структуры предложения.

Этим предложением герой пытается объяснить некоторую ситуацию. Он мог бы сказать: "Может, она и рада была бы, да у нее просто никак не получается, ведь это непростые ребята (у них твердый характер)". По смыслу, как мне кажется, слово "просто" относится к обеим частям. Но предложение такое длинное, что просится пауза, чтобы перевести дух.

Вполне можно сказать: "Просто эти ребята с твердым характером, и у нее просто никак не получается их смягчить".

Непростые ребята и просто не получается —  в одном случае просто — частица, в другом — прилагательное.

Зачем повторять дважды частицу?

Я просто хотела показать, что если переставить слово "просто", то нормально звучит. Конечно, писать так не стоит.
